# Find the surface area obtained by rotating $y=1+3x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x=2$ about the y-axis.

Tags: calculus, rotations, surfaces

Find the surface area obtained by rotating $y= 1+3 x^2$ from $x=0$ to $x = 2$ about the $y$-axis.

Having trouble evaluating the integral:

Solved for $x$:

- $x=0, y=1$
- $x=2, y=13$

$$\int_1^{13} 2\pi\sqrt\frac{y-1}3 \cdot \sqrt{1+\sqrt\frac{y-1}3'}^2\,dy$$

I got stuck at 2\pi\sqrt\frac{y-1}3 \cdot \sqrt{1+(1/12)+(1/(y-1))}

any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [Pappus's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem) and integrating in $x$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^22\pi x\,\overbrace{\sqrt{y'^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\mathrm{d}s}
&=\int_0^22\pi x\sqrt{36x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi{36}\int_0^2\sqrt{36x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}(36x^2+1)\\
&=\frac\pi{36}\int_1^{145}\sqrt{u}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac\pi{36}\left[\frac23u^{3/2}\right]_1^{145}\\[4pt]
&=\frac\pi{54}\left(145^{3/2}-1\right)
\end{align}
$$
where we used the substitution $u=36x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $((\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{3}})')^2=(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{y-1}{3}}} (1/3))^2=\frac{1}{4(y-1)}$
$$=\int_1^{13} 2\pi\sqrt\frac{y-1}3 \cdot \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4(y-1)}}dy
\\= \int_1^{13} 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{y-1}3+\frac{1}{12}}dy
\\= \int_1^{13} 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{y}3-\frac{1}{4}}dy
\\=  6\pi\{(\frac{y}3-\frac{1}{4})^\frac{3}{2}\}_1^{13}$$

Comment: I think the square of the derivative in the first line should be $\frac1{12(y-1)}$

Comment: Fixing that, I get the same result as I got in my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right